# Flutter Web - Widgets not resizing with browser zoom

Tags: flutter, user-interface, resize

I am currently building a Flutter web application and have encountered an issue where some of my widgets do not resize properly with the browser zoom. When the user decreases the zoom level, some of the widgets become cutoff and disappear from the screen.

I would like to request help in finding a solution to ensure that all of my widgets remain fully visible and properly resized regardless of the user's browser zoom level.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Open the Flutter web application in a browser.
2. Zoom in or out using the browser zoom controls.
3. Observe that some of the widgets become cutoff and disappear from the screen when zoomed out too       far.

**Expected Behavior**
All widgets should remain fully visible and properly resized with the browser zoom, without becoming cutoff or disappearing from the screen.

**Technical Information**
Flutter version: Flutter (Channel master, 3.8.0-7.0.pre.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.631], locale en-US)
Browser: Google Chrome
Operating System: Windows 10

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in the Flutter web core code, I have reported it on the official GitHub repository. You can check out the issue here for updates on when it will be fixed:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/129182